# Azure Service Bus - slow 99th percentile in messageSender.SendAsync

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have following code in dotnet core

```
using (mt.TrackElapsed("Send.Time"))
{
  await messageSender.SendAsync(busMessage);
}
```

The 99th percentile is around half to one second, depends on the service instance. It is quite long.

Details:

- messageSender is Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageSender
- dotnet core 2.1 and 2.2
- PaaS using Application Service Environment and AKS - Some services are on AKS, but most are on ASE.
- NuGet microsoft.azure.servicebus version 3.3.0

The question: is it my mistake or you have same results?

Comment: If you want performance, don't send a single message and await. Send multiple messages w/o awaiting, store the tasks, and await for the tasks with `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: I don't send so many messages in a short time. I send 1000-10000 a day (depends on the service), so your proposition doesn't solve mine problem. Anyway, it is a good idea, just not applicable in my case.

Comment: With 10,000 messages, that's less than a message per second. Mind if I ask why are you concerned about single message sending time being in the range of a second when you send at most 1 msg/sec?

Comment: Because it is strange from the engineering perspective. And the question is if I scale up does it mean that still every 1 from 100 customers will be affected with slow endpoint? Or it is normal with ServiceBus :)

Comment: Taking a tiny piece of code from the entire system with send/receive and benchmarking it might not be the right approach. I would love to see how do you manage your sender, what's the path to this call looks like. Are you running inside or outside of the Azure data centre. Even if you have 100 customers, if your daily throughput is 10K msg, that's 0.1 msg/sec. I can guarantee no customer will complaint. ZeroMQ would be much faster. Maybe you need an alternative?

Comment: That why I asked: "is it my mistake or you have the same results?". If people around the world have similar results I can think about an alternative, if not it is something wrong with my code :)